# Проверка текста

Tags: android

Есть атрибуты в моей view который "делает" все заголовки по умолчанию большими. Как правильно сделать проверку в коде на данный функционал, учитывая что я обращусь к view через активити findviewbyid ?

1. В моем файле .xml для моего кастомного текста проставленно значение: `app:allCaps="true"`
2. Теперь в своём тестовом классе хочу проставлять/проверять значения для данного текста.
3. В тестовом классе пытаюсь обратиться к данному элементу этой view следующим образом: `getActivity().findViewById(R.id.headerTitle)`
     + далее так понимаю нужно будет тут же продолжить проставлять значения true. Но при попытке вызвать активти через метод `getActivity` - выделяет ошибку Unresolve reference.(видимо как то не так обращаюсь к атрибутам view?)

Comment: В классе вашей вьюхи создайте `boolean` переменную и проверяйте если атрибут через xml задан то помимо установки большого заголовка менять её состояние на `true`. Для проверки из активности достаточно реализовать в классе вьюхи метод геттер, возвращающий эту `boolean` переменную. Ну и все

Comment: создал boolean переменную для своей кастомной textView: 'app:allCaps="true"' . В классе теста хочу всегда менять это значение на true, начинаю писать следующее 'getActivity.findViewById(R.id.headerTitle)' но сразу же подчеркивает  getActivity красным. + наверное не совсем правильно понял как можно менять её состояние на true

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что у вас не получается.

Comment: @СергейГрушин обновил вопрос, надеюсь сейчас стало более понятней проблема.

Comment: getActivity() - это метод фрагмента. Чем вас не устраивает [готовый атрибут `android:textAllCaps = "true"`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textAllCaps), он имеет связвнный метод `setAllCaps(boolean)` и соответственно установить капс для текста просто: `findViewById(R.id.some).setAllCaps(true);`

Comment: @pavlofff ну тогда у меня 'findViewById' становится 'Unresolve reference.' Ведь если я правильн понимаю нужно обращться к активити где находится моя view

Comment: Откуда вы пытаетесь вызвать этот метод, из какого класса?

Comment: Стоп. Вы пишете кастомную `View`?

Comment: Отметьте верный ответ галочкой

Answer (score 1):

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.headerTitle);
tv.setAllCaps(true); //установка верхнего регистра
tv.setAllCaps(false); //снятие верхнего регистра

//метод для проверки `textAllCaps`
public boolean isAllCaps(String text){
return (text.equals(text.toUpperCase()));
}

//Использование метода
if(isAllCaps(tv.getText().toString())) {
//если полностью верхний регистр
}
else{
//если есть хоть 1 символ в нижнем регистре
}
```